# Saving data efficiently in dynamoDB table

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have dynamoDB structure like this:

```
id: 9819938466
dt: 230822063230
code: 22
```

ID is 10 digit mobile number treated as username.

DT is current date + Time

CODE is the actual value that I need to store.

I expect about a few thousand unique ID's to record their code.
The total number of rows will not be more than a million.
Is my table structure as per industry standard?

Comment: How you have to store data is entirely dependent on how you want to access it. And you also do not state what the PK and the SK is.

Comment: I will need a report of a userID once in a month

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you don't state what is your partition and sort key, but my guess is that ID is your partition key and DT is your sort key. This will allow you to fetch all the codes for a given user in a given time range efficiently and is your best data model.

Comment: Yes. ID is partition key and DT is sort key. Is it possible to store millions of mobile numbers (ID)? Or is there a limit?

Comment: There is no limit, so long as you don't create an LSI, in which there would be a 10gb limit per user ID